# Ajax call does not return anything

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to get my way around the following for about 4-5 hrs already.

Basically, I have an HTML form which contains drop down populated from a database and Submit button. Based on the value selected, I would like to display related details into a table without refreshing the details. The problem is that I am struggling to understand why the jQuery Ajax does not do anything.

**HTML FORM:**

```
   <form name="jobIDs" method= "POST">
         <label for="valuelist">Job ID </label>
         <select name="jobList" id= "jobList">;     
                     <?php                            
                       $value= $_POST ["jobList"];

                       $db->sql('SELECT jobID FROM jobmaster ORDER BY jobID');
                       $result= $db->getResult();
                        foreach($result as $output){
                        echo '<option   value="'.$output['jobID'].'">'.$output['jobID'].'</option>';
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                     ?>
         <input type="submit" id="jobID-submit" value="Submit">
         </form>  

<table id="jobDetails">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Detail</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>      
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jobDetails.js"></script>
```

**AJAX**

```
            $('input#jobID-submit').on('click',function(){
            var jobid= document.getElementById('jobList').value;
        //  alert (jobid);
              function makeAjaxRequest() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/s2_jobDetails.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {jobList: jobid},
                        success: function(response) {
                       $('table#jobDetails tbody').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
```

**MYSQL/PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["jobList"])) {

$value= $_POST["jobList"];

.......connection + mysql query...

foreach ($result as $output){



    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> Job ID: </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $output['jobID'] . '</td>' ;
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    echo '<td> Quote ID: </td>' ;
    echo '<td>' . $output['quoteID'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

**Submit button- element inspection**

200- POST - section_2.php
304- GET -jobDetails.js

Comment: So why don't you look at the response in the network tool? You will see what's being returned.

Comment: it probably is, but since you're not preventing the click from bubbling onward, the normal form submission itself will proceed and kill your ajax request when the browser leaves your form page to proceed on to the form submission/results page.

Comment: what is the status code of the xhr

Comment: how do i prevent the bubbling? Do I have to add something to the .js ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending request to    `'ajax/s2_jobDetails.php'` and if this is the PHP file shown here then it seems you are sending HTML content. please specify the type of content you shall be receiving like HTML, JSON etc